# Concat cells of multiple rows into one row

Tags: sql, sql-server, view, pivot, sql-server-2012-express

I have a really weird requirement for my SQL Server table and I'm not sure if it is impossible to solve.

I have a client-side grid/table which displays data by a given T-SQL query/stored procedure. The table in the SQL Server database that I am looking at is numeric data with timestamps - something like this:

```
| DateTime(Key)          | Value  |
+------------------------+--------+
| 2010-07-27 17:00:00.00 | 1.337  |
| 2010-07-27 18:00:00.00 | 2.453  |
| 2010-07-27 19:00:00.00 | 3.2342 |
```

The requirement now is to display more 'value'-columns in one row like so:

```
| DateTime(Key)          | Value  | Value  | Value  |
+------------------------+--------+--------+--------+
| 2010-07-27 17:00:00.00 | 1.337  | 2.453  | 3.2342 |
| 2010-07-27 20:00:00.00 | 4.432  | 5.3422 | 6.9484 |
```

(**Attention:** The successive first numbers are just for readability)

Now I would like to create a view/stored procedure which allows me to provide the column I would like to have multiple of and the amount.

I have no idea how to approach this. Because you have to look at the next x rows and remove them and apply them to the first one.

Comment: (1) Tag your question with the database you are using.  (2) What do you mean "which allows me to provide the column I would like to have multiple of and the amount."?

Comment: This is indeed odd, I assume you are displaying anything from 17:00 to 19:00 on one row, then skipping to 20:00 to 22:00, etc.  I have no idea why you would want to do this, but it could all be achieved with a `GROUP BY` statement and some `CASE` statements as far as I can see.  If you provide some test data then I'm sure someone could provide a solution?

Comment: Actually, re-reading your question you want to have a variable number of rows pivoted this way.  This is almost certainly going to have to be dynamic, which means a stored procedure is probably the best solution.  You could either look at dynamic `PIVOT` or do something clever with `LEAD` (also constructing the query dynamically).

Comment: @GordonLinoff (1) done (2) the grid actually takes any generic query, so i explained it with my knowledge that i explained poorly. For the example above i should have just asked for the 'count'. So in this case the column 'Value' 3 times.

Comment: @woodyplz, Try my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer which is not fully dynamic yet, but it solves the basic requirement. I will post the fully dynamic stored procedure later.

```
DECLARE @Count int;
SET @Count = 3;

SELECT TimeUtc, V1, V2, V3 FROM (
SELECT 
    TimeUtc,
    Value as V1,
    LEAD(Value, 1, null) over (ORDER BY TimeUtc) AS V2,
    LEAD(Value, 2, null) over (ORDER BY TimeUtc) AS V3, 
    (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY TimeUtc) - 1) % @Count AS RN
FROM MeasurementData
WHERE 
) as tbl where RN = 0;
```

It would've been nice if I did not need the outer select, but i did not find a way around it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @Tab TABLE(DateTime DateTime, Value NUMERIC(8,5))

INSERT INTO @Tab VALUES('2010-07-27 17:00:00.00',1.337)
INSERT INTO @Tab VALUES('2010-07-27 18:00:00.00',2.453)
INSERT INTO @Tab VALUES('2010-07-27 19:00:00.00',3.2342)
INSERT INTO @Tab VALUES('2010-07-27 20:00:00.00',4.432)
INSERT INTO @Tab VALUES('2010-07-27 21:00:00.00',5.3422)
INSERT INTO @Tab VALUES('2010-07-27 22:00:00.00',6.9484)

SELECT MIN(D.DateTime)DateTime
    ,MIN(CASE WHEN D.RN=1 THEN D.Value END)Value1
    ,MIN(CASE WHEN D.RN=2 THEN D.Value END)Value2
    ,MIN(CASE WHEN D.RN=3 THEN D.Value END)Value3
FROM(
    SELECT *
        ,(CAST(Value AS INT)-1)/3 Val
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY (CAST(Value AS INT)-1)/3 ORDER BY DateTime)RN
    FROM @Tab
    )D
GROUP BY val
```

**Result:**

```
DateTime                Value1  Value2  Value3
2010-07-27 17:00:00.000 1.33700 2.45300 3.23420
2010-07-27 20:00:00.000 4.43200 5.34220 6.94840
```

Comment: hey thanks for the quick answer, i tried for my own for the last hour with LEAD which seemed promissing. I will try yours now, which looks really good!

Comment: @woodyplz, Yeah, happy to hear this. You are welcome...!

Comment: This is not dynamic and cant handle x rows. Use a dynamic pivot script.

Comment: I think I know understand what you were doing. With '(CAST(Value AS INT)-1)/3 ' you are dividing the value before the '.'(dot) and using it to identify the rownumber to group with.

I just used successive first numbers to help people understand my example. Sadly it just caused confusion. :(